# Change Listview of Navigation Drawer to any Custom View (Say Relative Layout)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-relativelayout, navigation-drawer

We have `ListView` to be displayed in our default **NavigationDrawer** by Android studio. Can we change that `ListView` to any other `Relative Layout`?

Can we write anything Custom?

Comment: Yes you can. Just replace the listView with your own layout in DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can Replace the `ListView` with any other customView like `RelativeLayout` Etc..
See my Example

in your `activity_main.xml` write a custom `relativeLayout` and give the layout Id in `MainActivity`'s `drawerLayout` like this,

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#0099cc"
            android:id="@+id/view" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu_imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/zone_name"
            android:text="Kitchen"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/menu_imageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dockedLayout"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_dock"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/master_volume"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Master Volume"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBarMasterVolume"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/master_volume"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    RelativeLayout mDockLayout;
    ImageView menu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_imageView);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDockLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dockedLayout);

        menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDockLayout);
            }
        });
    }
```